# How to set the maximum TCP receive window size in Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp

I want to limit the rate of every TCP connection. Can I set the maximum TCP receive window size in Linux?

With iptables + tc can only limit IP source. The parameters net.core.rmem_max and net.core.wmem_max didn't not work well.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` parameter to change the TCP window size where the three values are minimum window, default window and maximum window respectively.

```
root@ghyt:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem
4096    8192    16384
```

For reasons I've never quite been able to figure out, the values that you set are only very loosely honored, but it should still allow you to reduce the maximum window advertised.

Alternatively, you can turn off TCP Window scaling (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling`) which will force all TCP connections to use a 64KB window. Maximum bandwidth them becomes a matter of distance:

Bandwidth (Mbit/s) = ((65535 * 8)/(latency in ms/1000))/1000000

Comment: The window size is automatically altered as per the flow control characteristics of that connection. The value you change sets the default tcp tries.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is, the "default" value never actually seems to be used when a new TCP connection is established. For example, my regular default value is 87380, however the window that initially gets advertised from my client is around 30k.